# How to add an entry into current process' page table?

Tags: linux

I would like to add some mappings into current process' page table. At first, I thought I can write what I want into page table by using "/dev/mem". But I am afraid that the middle page tables (take x86_64 as an example, pdpt, pdt and pt) are not allocated yet. Is there a way to
add entries into current process' page table? Thanks.

Comment: The normal way is `mmap`. If you can explain why you want to go behind the kernel's back...

Comment: You can see this thread http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2012-08/msg04407.html to know what Im trying to do more or less. How can I use mmap to add what I want into page tables? Could you explain more? Thanks.

Comment: Read carefully the man pages of `mmap(2)` and `mprotect(2)` syscalls.

Comment: You mean I mmap virtual address below 4G first, so that the corresponding (middle) page tables are allocated. Then I write what I want through /dev/mem?